# How do I destroy/update Chart Data in this chart.js code example?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Happy New Year! 
I'm tussling with the need to destroy or update chart data, so that on reload of the chart it doesn't show the presence of the previous data on mouseover.

I've seen the example on [Chart.js's API page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html?h=destroy), and looked over numerous examples on SO, but none seem to match how my code was written by another developer. Could someone show me how using myLineChart.destroy(); or myLineChart.update(); can be applied?

The code:

```
// Display the chart
showChart = function (data, chartPosition) {
    console.log(chartPosition)
    new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart-" + chartPosition), {
        type: 'line',    
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                fillStyle: Color,
                strokeStyle: Color,
                labels: {
                usePointStyle: true,
                fontSize: 12,
                boxWidth: 10,
            }
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Main Title'
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
           return data.datasets[tooltipItems[0].datasetIndex].label;
                    },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return "$" + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(0).replace(/./g, function(c, i, a) {
                return i > 0 && c !== "." && (a.length - i) % 3 === 0 ? "," + c : c;
            });
            }
    }
},
            scales: {
  xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
         callback: function(value, index, values) {
         return value + ' years';
                }
                }
  }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function (value, index, values) {
                            return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You need to be saving your chart to a variable. So where `new Chart` is being called, set it to something like `var myChart = new Chart`. You can read about class constructors (Chart is the class, constructor is what happens when you call `new`) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). After that you'll be able to perform operations on your variable (like `myChart.destroy`).

Comment: Thanks. Do I set the variable ahead of the existing showChart line or does it need to be set within the showChart function?

Comment: It needs to bet set wherever you initialize your chart, so in this case it would be inside the `showChart` function -- `showChart = function() { var myChart = new Chart... }`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I've set the var myChart. Where would it be best to implement the             myChart.destroy(); ?

Comment: I can't exactly determine that without seeing more of your code (CodePen or JSFiddle would be nice) but you'll probably want to set your variable outside of the function and then clear as needed: `var myChart = null; showChart = function(...) { if (myChart !== null) { myChart.destroy(); } myChart = ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Chart.js provides a helper class from which you can access all the chart instances on a page.

If you want to destroy all the instances before update/reload use the following code:

```
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
         instance.destroy();
    });
```

If you want to destroy a particular chart using the canvas id, use the following code:

```
Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function (instance) {
        if (instance.chart.canvas.id === "yourChartId") {
            instance.destroy();
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Also, this method avoids the overhead of storing a chart in a variable on creation.

Comment: Not a bad solution but there are other ways to update the chart

Comment: Yes, we can use the same helper class to update a particular chart or all, very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the data used by the chart directly.

From there documentation

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Here you can pass the new data with the reference to the chart object. You can save the reference wwhen you create `new Chart(...)`.

This is helpful to render the charts faster and in a smooth manner.